# WGL bug in MinGW

Tags: opengl, mingw, mesa, wgl

I'm having issues with wglext.h in MinGW. The version from Visual Studio isn't working (compiler screams about missing defines).

So I tried using mesa-dev and compiling it with MinGW - and I get bug

```
Fatal error: glapi.h: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: So I successfully compiled mesa's libopengl32.a - but now comes another issue - see here: http://oi44.tinypic.com/nn5put.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So again answering my question.

SOLVED!

You have to link against OpenGL32 and GDI32 after object files (for some unknown reasons).

So instead of (I'm using a makefile, so unpacked it'll look like)

```
g++ -lopengl32 -lgdi32 main.o -o main
```

one must use

```
g++ main.o -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -o main
```

Comment: The documentation of GCC clearly states, that order of files is important and libraries should always be defined after compilation units when linking